# R Dplyr Add Rows Total

Tags: r, dplyr, tally

```
    HAVE = data.frame(STUDENT = c(1,2,3,4),
YEAR = c(2020,2020,2021,2020),
                      SCORE1 = c(5,9,8,0),
                      TEST = c(7,11,3,9))
    
    WANT = data.frame(STUDENT = c(1,2,3,4, 'ALL'),
YEAR = c(2020, 2020, 2021, 2020,NA),
                      SCORE1 = c(5,9,8,0,22),
                       TEST = c(7,11,3,9,30))
```

I have 'HAVE' and wish to create 'WANT' which does this:
Add row to HAVE where STUDENT = 'ALL' and SCORE1 = sum up all values of SCORE and TEST = sum up all values of TEST.

I try this with no success:

```
WANT = rowbind(HAVE, data.frame(STUDENT = 'ALL', SCORE1 = sum(HAVE$SCORE1), TEST = sum(HAVE$TEST))
```

But is there a efficient DPLYR solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

HAVE %>% 
  mutate(STUDENT = as.character(STUDENT)) %>% 
  bind_rows(summarise(.,
                      across(where(is.numeric), sum),
                      across(where(is.character), ~"All")))
```

```
  STUDENT SCORE1 TEST
1       1      5    7
2       2      9   11
3       3      8    3
4       4      0    9
5     All     22   30
```

**OR**
Maybe with `janitor` package:

```
libray(dplyr)
library(janitor)
HAVE %>% 
  adorn_totals("row")
```

```
 STUDENT SCORE1 TEST
       1      5    7
       2      9   11
       3      8    3
       4      0    9
   Total     22   30
```

Comment: this is so perfect! Let us say there are some other COLUMNS and you Wish for 'Total' for those to be empty, can you specify to leave blank? Like If there is column YEAR, we don't want to sum up YEAR...we just wish it to be NA

Comment: i update question for example

Comment: In my first solution dplyr only just add this line `across(c(YEAR), ~ NA_real_))) %>% ...` Here you specify all columns with `c()` that you want to keep NA. Hope it is clear?!

Answer (score 4):

Or in `base R` with `addmargins`

```
addmargins(as.matrix(HAVE[-(1:2)]), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this works! Use rbind or bind_rows.

```
HAVE = data.frame(STUDENT = c(1,2,3,4),
                  SCORE1 = c(5,9,8,0),
                  TEST = c(7,11,3,9)) %>% 
  mutate(STUDENT = as.character(STUDENT))

WANT = bind_rows(HAVE, data.frame(STUDENT = 'ALL', SCORE1 = sum(HAVE$SCORE1),
                                  TEST = sum(HAVE$TEST)))


or

WANT <- rbind(HAVE, data.frame(STUDENT = 'ALL', SCORE1 = sum(HAVE$SCORE1), TEST = sum(HAVE$TEST)))
```